# Review items appear twice

Tags: support, review

While reviewing questions (first and late), I noticed that questions I've reviewed as first posts, also appear on the late post section afterwards. Should this be the case?

See example: [first post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/7662)

I've reviewed it as "not an answer" as first post.

And here it is as [late answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/7662)

Comment: Possibly the same question was asked on Meta SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157262/duplicate-low-quality-post-in-first-post-late-answer-double-flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug per-se if a post qualifies to be on multiple review queues. More eyes to take a look at.

Comment: I like to review first posts a bit different to late posts. I'd rather add a constructive remark and make them "feel at home" then down vote or flag.